# How to set up Ruby on Rails Action Mailbox with Amazon SES?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses, action-mailbox

I'm trying to migrate the email sending and receiving service from another mail provider to Amazon SES. The action mailer is working fine, but I tried for a while and didn't find any documentation on how to receive emails with SES, except some blog posts claim that Action Mailbox supports SES:

> It comes with ingresses for Amazon SES, Mailgun...

There is only documentation on the official guides for Mailgun and Sendgrid, and several others but no SES. Any thoughts on where should I start?

Answer (score 3):

It was removed 2 years ago. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f480cfabcd9000b5817b610e21466299025b12d2). Since 2020 there has also been [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39364) which is still open at the moment I write this.

However, the functionality of that PR has been published as [`action_mailbox_amazon_ingress`](https://github.com/bobf/action_mailbox_amazon_ingress). There is some talk to port it to [`aws-sdk-rails`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails).